# Как узнать версию пакета установленного через composer?

Tags: php, composer

Добрый день. Подскажите пожалуйста как узнать версию пакета установленного через композер? В пакете мешанина файлов, из которых не совсем понятна его версия. В самом загруженном composer.json указано 2.4.x, то есть окончания не понятно в данном случае. В другом файле написано 2.3.x.

В общем не могу разобрать точную версию без x.
Спасибо

Answer (score 7, accepted):

См. [документацию](https://getcomposer.org/doc/03-cli.md#show):

```
php composer.phar show -i
```

Answer (score 1):

Получить информацию о конкретном установленном пакете:

```
php composer.phar show -- vendor/package
```

Смотреть на строку `versions : ...`